# How to iterate over rows and drop all other rows where column matches?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to go row by row in a dataframe and delete any rows that have the same 'hole_ID' but keep the original row. So that the nearest neighbour only searches in different holes. Here's what I have so far:

```python
import pandas as pd
s1 = StringIO(u'''east,north,elev,hole_ID
11,11,5,A
51,51,6,A
61,61,11,A
21,21,2,B
31,31,3,B
71,71,3,B
81,81,4,B''')

df2 = pd.read_csv(s1)

for idx,row in df2.iterrows():
    dftype= df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['hole_ID'], keep='first')
```

This is what I get:

```python
Out[20]: 
   east  north  elev hole_ID
0    11     11     5       A
3    21     21     2       B
```

And this is what I want to get:

```python
Out[18]: 
   east  north  elev hole_ID
0    11     11     5       A
3    21     21     2       B
4    31     31     3       B
5    71     71     3       B
6    81     81     4       B
```

So for row 1, all the other rows with the same hole_ID ('A') are dropped.

EDIT: I need to do this for every row in the original data frame to perform a nearest neighbour calculation where the hole_ID's do not match.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to iterate over rows to do this, `drop_duplicates` works on the entire dataframe at once. In your question you say you want to "delete any rows that have the same 'hole_ID'" but in your output, you've only removed duplicates on `A` `hole_ID`s. You might want to specify in your question.

Comment: Added an edit. I'm not sure how to word it, I'm trying to iterate over rows to perform a nearest neighbour search where the hole_ID's don't match.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to drop duplicates where `hole_ID` is `A`, you can `pd.concat` on a one side the dataframe indexed when that is true and dropping duplicates, and on the other the rest of the cases:

```
pd.concat([ 
    df2[df2.hole_ID.eq('A')].drop_duplicates(subset=['hole_ID'], keep='first'),
    df2[df2.hole_ID.ne('A')]],
    axis=0)

    east  north  elev hole_ID
0    11     11     5       A
3    21     21     2       B
4    31     31     3       B
5    71     71     3       B
6    81     81     4       B
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function. Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) 
to be able to select different ID

```
def remove_by_hole_ID(df,hole_ID):
    if not isinstance(hole_ID,list):
        hole_ID = [hole_ID]
    m = df['hole_ID'].isin(hole_ID)
    return pd.concat([df[m].drop_duplicates(subset = 'hole_ID'),df[~m]],sort = True)
```

---

```
print(remove_by_hole_ID(df,'A'))
   east  elev hole_ID  north
0    11     5       A     11
3    21     2       B     21
4    31     3       B     31
5    71     3       B     71
6    81     4       B     81


print(remove_by_hole_ID(df,['A','B']))
   east  elev hole_ID  north
0    11     5       A     11
3    21     2       B     21
```